# Search for a simple and useful programming idea

Tags: project

I'm learning and doing projects on Grails, but for now it's a little boring because of the repetitive work (GORM, fix bug,...) . I want to "play" a little: making something simple, but useful, so that I can get inspired again with the programing work. For example, I think of something like [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/), or [RainCalendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php), or Google StreetView.

The problem is that I'm just a lone programmer, and don't have lots of time for developing my own software. So I posted this question to ask for:

1. Some idea about a simple-coding program, but useful, interesting (funny is a bonus).
2. Some where (online) for programmer like me can find interesting project to join? I can code C, C++, Java, Grails and PHP. But other languages is also welcome.

I'll appreciate any idea from everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Answer your Second question:
[sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/develop/)
And that has a lot of projects running so take a look at their Project Help Wanted board
then join the one you like.

And that should in turn answer your first question